# How to have menu items stretched in full width menu with css for any screen automatically

Tags: css, menu

I have menu items that must be stretched automatically in full width menu.How is the best way for any type of screen to do it automatically with css?

I tried this

```
.report_types_section ul li {
 position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
}.report_types_section ul li a {
 float: left;
text-decoration: none;
 color: #74a9d4;
font-size: 18px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 35px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}.report_types_section ul li a:after {
 content: " | ";
color: #74a9d4;
font-size: 18px;
float: right;
padding-left: 23px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

But for any screen here I need to increase the padding but it is not good.

Comment: to broad. it depends on where you are trying to achieve this. At the most basic level you don't even need to consider for screens (which means no @media queries required). `width: 100%` works at the basic level. improve your question.

Comment: I need to have the menu items streched for following size, for example do not give a fixed width to the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for the spaces.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5qr3oap/)

```
.report_types_section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 64%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.report_types_section ul li:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.report_types_section ul li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.report_types_section ul li.active_tab a {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.report_types_section ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 0;
}
.report_types_section ul li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}
.report_types_section ul li:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.report_types_section ul li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.report_types_section ul li a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  border-right: 1px solid #74a9d4;
}
```

Comment: You may notice how AtanuCSE has taken your code and actually put it in the answer. This is what you should have done to begin with, otherwise you run the very real risk of having your answers downvoted and removed for being link-only answers.

Comment: Thank you J.Steen!Will fix it for future.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of having provided any markup- I have made a few inferences- what you wish to achieve can be used with CSS tables (in the absence of greater support for flexbox)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.report_types_section ul {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.report_types_section ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
.report_types_section ul li:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 1px solid #74a9d4;
}
.report_types_section ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #74a9d4;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="report_types_section">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

You can also apply `white-space: nowrap;` to the child `a` to prevent wrapping.

Comment: it is a good solution only I didnt need the space from the left and right that was remaining, the first item and the last item must not have space on the left and last one on the right @SW4.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items will be there, you can use columns with percentage width. For example 6 elements - 100% / 6

```
.report_types_section ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16.6%;
    float: left;
}
```

DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/hzy5Lr49/

---

EDIT

I have no better idea than using table layout and adding empty cells as spacing cells. I also put a pipe `|` in empty cells and centered it to simulate border.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/hzy5Lr49/2/

Comment: Thank you only I didnt need the space on the left that has the first item, and also the space on the right that has the last item @mkutyba

Comment: What a weird design ;) I will try.

Comment: Yeah you are right!Thank you very much @mkutyba for helping me, I tried many styles to remove this spaces but till couldnt!